# Samba TimeMachine folder on the External drive doesn't work

Tags: debian, backup, samba, macos

I'm wondering if there is an issue to use the external drive as a Time Machine network folder for MacOS.

When I spotted the problem, the drive was formatted to exFAT, so I tried to format it as a ext4 to be same as the system/home drive.

The issue I have encountered is that I can use the timemachine application (MacOS -> Samba) on folder in the system drive, but not on folder in the usb external drive.

I had default `smb.conf` and I proceed according to instructions on this site:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_Samba_to_Work_Better_with_Mac_OS_X

`/media/pipi/MACBCK` is mounted external drive and because I have been able to use Time Machine with `pipi` folder and tried same thing in the internal folder `/MACBCK/pipi` which works (Timemachine Backup 2).

```
ls -lA /MACBCK/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 pipi pipi 4096 Nov 27 17:53 pipi
```

```
ls -lA /media/pipi/MACBCK/
total 20
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Nov 27 16:07 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx 2 pipi pipi  4096 Nov 27 16:17 pipi
```

```
[global]
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes

# Time Machine settings
   vfs objects = fruit streams_xattr
   fruit:metadata = stream
   fruit:model = MacSamba
   fruit:posix_rename = yes
   fruit:veto_appledouble = no
   fruit:nfs_aces = no
   fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
   fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[Timemachine Backup]
   comment = MacOS Timemachine Folder
   path = /media/pipi/MACBCK/pipi
   guest ok = no
   browseable = no
   writable = yes
   valid users = pipi
   fruit:time machine = yes

[Timemachine Backup 2]
   comment = MacOS Timemachine 2 Folder
   path = /MACBCK/pipi
   guest ok = no
   browseable = no
   writable = yes
   valid users = pipi
   fruit:time machine = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to follow this tutorial? https://saschaeggi.medium.com/use-a-raspberry-pi-4-for-time-machine-works-with-big-sur-1e66a9650789.

Your two folders don't have the same rights and that won't work.

Comment: Welcome to U&L SE. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible.